# Create new pandas dataframe from an existing one only with max and min per day

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following df

```
 ID       Date Element  Data_Value  day  month  year
24805  USW00094889 2005-01-01    TMIN         -56    1      1  2005
24863  USW00094889 2005-01-01    TMAX          44    1      1  2005
18049  USW00014853 2005-01-01    TMAX          56    1      1  2005
18066  USW00014853 2005-01-01    TMIN         -39    1      1  2005
10073  USW00014833 2005-01-01    TMAX          33    1      1  2005
10079  USW00014833 2005-01-01    TMIN         -44    1      1  2005
60994  USW00004848 2005-01-01    TMAX         133    1      1  2005
60995  USW00004848 2005-01-01    TMIN           0    1      1  2005
32266  USC00208202 2005-01-01    TMAX         150    1      1  2005
32274  USC00208202 2005-01-01    TMIN         -50    1      1  2005
41309  USC00208080 2005-01-01    TMIN         -39    1      1  2005
41334  USC00208080 2005-01-01    TMAX          33    1      1  2005
17153  USC00207320 2005-01-01    TMAX         150    1      1  2005
17155  USC00207320 2005-01-01    TMIN         -11    1      1  2005
49030  USC00207312 2005-01-01    TMAX         150    1      1  2005
49074  USC00207312 2005-01-01    TMIN         -39    1      1  2005
55424  USC00207308 2005-01-01    TMAX         150    1      1  2005
55428  USC00207308 2005-01-01    TMIN         -44    1      1  2005
1906   USC00205822 2005-01-01    TMIN         -17    1      1  2005
3058   USC00205822 2005-01-01    TMAX         128    1      1  2005
39454  USC00205563 2005-01-01    TMAX          28    1      1  2005
39468  USC00205563 2005-01-01    TMIN         -28    1      1  2005
31715  USC00205451 2005-01-01    TMAX         156    1      1  2005
31718  USC00205451 2005-01-01    TMIN         -44    1      1  2005
19769  USC00205450 2005-01-01    TMIN         -33    1      1  2005
19772  USC00205450 2005-01-01    TMAX         128    1      1  2005
18232  USC00205050 2005-01-01    TMIN         -17    1      1  2005
18261  USC00205050 2005-01-01    TMAX          56    1      1  2005
2073   USC00203712 2005-01-01    TMAX         144    1      1  2005
2812   USC00203712 2005-01-01    TMIN         -50    1      1  2005
```

I need a new df with only the MAX and MIN per day,
ID Means weather stations, so I need the min and max of all weather stations per day

I found this but doesnt seem to do what I need:
https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-get-the-maximum-values-of-each-group-in-a-pandas-dataframe-in-python

EDIT:
I need the max min, per day across all weather stations across all years in dataframe.!
Because later I will need to plot this:
https://d3c33hcgiwev3.cloudfront.net/imageAssetProxy.v1/O7lHul3pRKK5R7pd6VSiDg_d08976af1b2e66455544ff7bfba54ac7_Screen-Shot-2020-07-22-at-1.47.24-PM.png?expiry=1626825600000&hmac=2phrz7iX32ed37OgFy0H9j7-lvqno_l_e2ELRW6JFio

Comment: When you say min/max, do you mean the highest/lowest data_value?

Comment: yes correct....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your min is defined by a single column, you can use the series groupby:

```
>>> df.groupby('Date')['Data_Value'].agg(['min', 'max'])
            min  max
Date                
2005-01-01  -56  156
```

If you want full rows, or other infos from that row, you can use `idxmin` and `idxmax` instead of `min` and `max`. Here it is with an additional column indicating whether it’s the min or max value row:

```
>>> idx = df.groupby('Date')['Data_Value'].agg(['idxmin', 'idxmax'])
>>> pd.concat({'min': df.loc[idx['idxmin']], 'max': df.loc[idx['idxmax']]}, names=['minmax']).reset_index('minmax')
      minmax           ID        Date Element  Data_Value  day  month  year
24805    min  USW00094889  2005-01-01    TMIN         -56    1      1  2005
31715    max  USC00205451  2005-01-01    TMAX         156    1      1  2005
```

Or somewhat simpler (without the extra column):

```
>>> df.loc[idx.stack()]
                ID        Date Element  Data_Value  day  month  year
24805  USW00094889  2005-01-01    TMIN         -56    1      1  2005
31715  USC00205451  2005-01-01    TMAX         156    1      1  2005
```

---

Since edit you want the min/max per day, across years:

```
>>> df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.dayofyear)['Data_Value'].agg(['min', 'max'])
      min  max
Date          
1     -56  156
```

The `Date` index will now range from 1 to 365 for your plot x-axis.
Note that dates and day-of-year numbers will be shifted by 1 depending on leap year:

```
>>> pd.Timestamp(2021, 3, 1).dayofyear
60
>>> pd.Timestamp(2020, 3, 1).dayofyear
61
```

If so you might prefer the actual dates, here’s 2 optins with 1 or 2 index levels:

```
>>> df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.strftime('%m-%d'))['Data_Value'].agg(['min', 'max'])
       min  max
Date           
01-01  -56  156
>>> df.groupby(['month', 'day'])['Data_Value'].agg(['min', 'max'])
           min  max
month day          
1     1    -56  156
```

Comment: actually I made a mistake, I need the max and min per day (not date), so the maximum and minimum across all weather stations and across all days of different years  (dataframe has several years)

Comment: please see Edit